# Determine most important feature per class

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection

Imagine a machine learning problem where you have 20 classes and about 7000 sparse boolean features.

I want to figure out what the 20 most unique features per class are. In other words, features that are used a lot in a specific class but aren't used in other classes, or hardly used.

What would be a good feature selection algorithm or heuristic that can do this?

Answer (score 6):

When you train a Logistic Regression multi-class classifier the train model is a num_class x num_feature matrix which is called the model where its [i,j] value is the weight of feature j in class i. The indices of features are the same as your input feature matrix.

In scikit-learn you can access to the parameters of the model
If you use scikit-learn classification algorithms you'll be able to find the most important features per class by:

```
clf = SGDClassifier(loss='log', alpha=regul, penalty='l1', l1_ratio=0.9, learning_rate='optimal', n_iter=10, shuffle=False, n_jobs=3, fit_intercept=True)
clf.fit(X_train, Y_train)
for i in range(0, clf.coef_.shape[0]):
    top20_indices = np.argsort(clf.coef_[i])[-20:]
    print top20_indices
```

clf.coef_ is the matrix containing the weight of each feature in each class so clf.coef_[0][2] is the weight of the third feature in the first class.
If when you build your feature matrix you keep track of the index of each feature in a dictionary where dic[id] = feature_name you'll be able to retrieve the name of the top feature using that dictionary.

For more information refer to [scikit-learn text classification example](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/document_classification_20newsgroups.html)

Answer (score 0):

Random Forest and Naive Bayes should be able to handle this for you.  Given the sparsity, I'd go for the Naive Bayes first.  Random Forest would be better if you're looking for combinations.

Comment: Pedantic rhetoric note:  You're looking for "distinctive" features.  There is no such thing as "most unique": the word "unique" means that there is exactly one, so there are no degrees of uniqueness.

Comment: I'm well aware of naive Bayes in terms of a classifier for prediction. But I'm not familiar with using naive Bayes as feature selector. I'm currently using chi^2 but that just gives me a ranking of all features, not per class. I'll have a look at random forest. Thanks