# Best way to get the top important features per class in binary classification?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, feature-selection

The closest answer i could find is this :

[Determine most important feature per class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33118361/determine-most-important-feature-per-class)

so based on that, i wrote this :

```
myClassifier = SGDClassifier( shuffle=False, fit_intercept=True , verbose=True)
myClassifier.fit(X_train, Y_train)



myfile = open("important_class_1.txt" , "w")

top_indices = np.argsort(myClassifier.coef_[0])[-250:]
print (top_indices)

for x in top_indices: 

    myfile.write(feature_list[int(x)] + "\n")

myfile.close()

myfile = open("important_class_0.txt" , "w")

top_indices = np.argsort(myClassifier.coef_[0])[:250]
print (top_indices)

for x in top_indices: 

    myfile.write(feature_list[int(x)] + "\n")


myfile.close()
```

So am i doing this correct? is this a good way to extract which features are the most important for to detect each class?

meaning, is this correct or not :

```
Most positive weights : important features for class 1 

Most negative weights : important features for class 0
```

(I'm double checking this because the question that i linked to didn't get much attention, so just wanted to make sure if the answer to it is really correct or not)

Comment: seems just fine.

Comment: For a binary classification, this approach (identifying important features for each class) doesn't make any sense for me but for multi class - this should be fine.

Comment: @Venkatachalam what do you mean? you mean the output is incorrect or..? and what should i do instead then